# Parametrized queries for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, sql, esri-geodatabase, security

Since our ArcGIS applications are developed as desktop and as server applications, I'm looking for a way create our SQL-queries in a safe way. The state of the art to mitigate SQL-injection is, to use [parametrized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) / prepared statements.

Prepared statements can only be implemented with support of the underlying database and I'm not aware that Esri offers support of those in their interfaces. Parametrized queries could partly be implemented in an external library.

Is anybody aware of a library, which offers parametrized queries for any of the ArcGIS products, or does Esri offer support for parametrized queries in one of their products?

---

Finally I opened an issue on [ArcGIS Pro Ideas](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/offer-quot-prepared-statements-quot-to-prevent-sql/idi-p/1133857).

Answer (score 6):

Out of the box, ArcGIS Server comes with two pieces of functionality you might explore:

1. Feature services have [`ValidateSQL`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Validate_SQL_Feature_Service_Layer/02r3000002ms000000/) request available which can check your SQL query/statement.

> `validateSQL` also prevents SQL injection. In addition, all table and
>   field names used in the SQL expression or WHERE clause are validated
>   to ensure they are valid tables and fields.

2. [Standardized queries](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/about-standardized-queries.htm) available in ArcGIS Server.

> ArcGIS Server includes a security option that forces developers to use
>   standardized SQL queries when working with map, feature, image, and
>   WFS services through REST or SOAP. This makes it easier for developers
>   and applications to query ArcGIS Server services and helps prevent `SQL injection attacks`. Standardized queries are enforced by default, but
>   can be disabled by the server administrator.
>
> The **standardized queries are enabled by default** and apply to all map,
>   feature, image, and WFS services in the ArcGIS Server site.

I am afraid parameterized queries is not something that is available out of the box and you would likely need to use 3rd party to integrate this. You might look at the [ArcGIS Server SOI](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-extending-services.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_22386DF3305F42D4997F6F4301F8A8D5) to learn more about intercepting incoming requests to your GIS services. SOI can be used for instance for:

> Auditing and logging all requests—For debugging purposes, you can
>   create a series of SOIs that log detailed information about incoming
>   requests, such as full information about the input parameters and the
>   user credentials passed in with the request.

This could help you building your extra layer of security if needed.